# How can I convert a std::string to UTF-8?

Tags: c++, json

I need to put a stringstream as a value of a JSON (using rapidjson library), but std::stringstream::str is not working because it is not returning UTF-8 characters. How can I do that?

Example:
`d["key"].SetString(tmp_stream.str());`

Comment: Do you mean `std::wstringstream`?  Because plain old ASCII strings are UTF8 compatible.  And also, which version of c++ are you using?  Do you already use boost?  Is it for Windows? The ytools available are different for these different environments.

Comment: There's no c++ standard support for character encoding yet, unfortunately.

Comment: `is not working because it is not returning UTF-8` How do you know that's the reason?

Comment: Put a UTF-8 string in a `std::string`, and *presto magicko* it will contain a UTF-8 string.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ   There is some support for c++11 and 14, but it was deprecated in c++17.  `std::codecvt_utf8()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rapidjson::Value::SetString` accepts a pointer and a length. So you have to call it this way:

```cpp
std::string stream_data = tmp_stream.str();
d["key"].SetString(tmp_stream.data(), tmp_string.size());
```

As others have mentioned in the comments, `std::string` is a container of `char` values with no encoding specified. It can contain UTF-8 encoded bytes or any other encoding.

I tested putting invalid UTF-8 data in an `std::string` and calling `SetString`. RapidJSON accepted the data and simply replaced the invalid characters with "?". If that's what you're seeing, then you need to:

1. Determine what encoding your string has
2. Re-encode the string as UTF-8

If your string is ASCII, then `SetString` will work fine as ASCII and UTF-8 are compatible.

If your string is UTF-16 or UTF-32 encoded, there are several lightweight portable libraries to do this like [utfcpp](https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp). C++11 *had* an API for this, but it was poorly supported and now deprecated as of C++17.

If your string encoded with a more archaic encoding like Windows-1252, then you might need to use either an OS API like [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) on Windows, or use a heavyweight Unicode library like [LibICU](https://icu.unicode.org/) to convert the data to a more standard encoding.